# Google Drive Web api (android app) - creating files work fine in debug, do not work in proguard

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to create simple android app which creates file. It works perfectly when debugging, however, when I export app with proguard, it is only creating files with name "UNTITLED". How is this possible? Content of file is correct, just title is always UNTITLED. Just for sure it is here:

```
File file = new File();
file.setTitle("hello.txt");
file.setMimeType(MIME_TYPE);

// file content
java.io.File temp = createTempFile("simple content");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(MIME_TYPE, temp);
File createdFile = service.files().insert(file, mediaContent).execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out the reason - it was definitely the proguard issue, solution was to add this to my proguard config:

```
-keep class com.google.api.** {*;}
```